# Potência no Java diferente do Excel

Tags: java, kotlin

Estou tendo um problema pra converter uma fórmula do Excel para o Java/Kotlin. O cenário é o seguinte, no Excel eu tenho:

Taxa de juros: `0.07`

Cálculo Excel:

```
=(1+taxaDeJuros)^12-1 = %125.22
```

No Kotlin:

```
val result = Math.pow((1+taxaDeJuros), 12.00 - 1)) = 2.104851952299
```

Se colocar no Excel a fórmula `=(1+taxaDeJuros)^(12-1)` o resultado será igual no Kotlin (`2.104851952299`), ou seja deu a entender que o Kotlin está colocando o parênteses no `(12.00-1)`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
val result = Math.pow((1 + taxaDeJuros), 12.00) - 1
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, vlw.

Answer (score 5):

O Kotlin não está "colocando parênteses", está apenas executando as coisas na ordem que você indicou.

O que acontece é que [`Math.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) é um método que recebe dois argumentos: a base e o expoente - e eles são separados por vírgula. Assim:

```
Math.pow( base, expoente )
```

Ou seja, em `Math.pow((1+taxaDeJuros), 12.00 - 1)`, a base é `(1 + taxaDeJuros)` (e esses parênteses poderiam até ser retirados) e o expoente é `12.00 - 1`. Então primeiro ele calcula esses valores, para depois chamar `Math.pow`.
Ou seja, é como se eu tivesse chamado `Math.pow(1 + taxaDeJuros, 11.0)`.

No caso do Excel, a avaliação da fórmula `(1+taxaDeJuros)^12-1` está usando [a ordem de precedência dos operadores](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculation-operators-and-precedence-in-excel-48be406d-4975-4d31-b2b8-7af9e0e2878a): primeiro calcula o que está dentro dos parênteses (`(1 + taxaDeJuros)`), depois faz a exponenciação (usando o expoente `12.0`), e por fim subtrai 1.

Se quer esse mesmo resultado em Kotlin, basta colocar a subtração fora da exponenciação:

```
val result = Math.pow(1 + taxaDeJuros, 12.0) - 1
```

Outra opção é usar [`kotlin.math.pow`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/pow.html), assim fica *um pouco* mais próximo da fórmula do Excel (e provavelmente assim fique mais claro a ordem em que cada operação é feita):

```
import kotlin.math.pow

val result = (1 + taxaDeJuros).pow(12.0) - 1
```

Assim acho que fica mais claro que primeiro ele faz a soma `1 + taxaDeJuros`, depois eleva a 12, e depois subtrai 1.

Repare também que não precisa de dois zeros depois do ponto, é redundante. `12.0` é o suficiente para indicar que é um `double`. E no segundo caso, o expoente também poderia ser apenas `12`:

```
import kotlin.math.pow

val result = (1 + taxaDeJuros).pow(12) - 1
```

[Veja no IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Mms2hC) todas as opções acima rodando.